# powering a 12V 1.0Amp DC fan

Tags: voltage, batteries

I want to make a compact, high volume fan, in an enclosed box. Weight, noise, and air volume are important. Can I power a 12V 1.0A; Speed: 3000RPM; Air flow: 38.5CFM; Noise:45dBA fan with a 12V and 2 AA batteries?

Comment: 2 AA batteries does not give 12 V, but 2-3 V.  Please revise your question.  "12V and 2 AA batteries" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: A small 12V remote battery is expensive and has a small capacity. It will die quickly.

Comment: what do you mean by `enclosed box`?

Comment: Are you referring to a 12V 2Ah battery?

Comment: Grossly under-powered.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to review the use of AA bateries due to the current of the fan you need.

Based in my experience you can use 4x 18650 lithium-ion batteries that gives you an output of 14.8v. After, connect them to an LM7812 voltage regulator. This regulator need a minimum voltage of 14.5-15v to operate so will work ok.
The output of this voltage regulator you have to connect it to the fan.
You can use to smooth the signal of the voltage regulator 2 caps in parallel of 100nf and 100uf.

Comment: What about the dissipation of the linear regulator? Does it require a heatsink? If yes, what size?

Comment: If the output of the lithium-ion batteries is 14.8V and the regulator output is 12V
you have a 2.8V drop. If you draw 1000mA the dissipation is 2.8 * 1000mA or 2.8W.  
The thermal resistance (Rja junction to air) of a TO-220 package is around
65 degC per W (from the datasheet). The maximum junction temperature
of the Fairchild part is 125DegC. In this example 2.8 * 65 = 182 degC rise.
For room temperature operation you have a junction temperature of 182 + 25 degC which is above the 125DegC maximum. In this case a heatsink of 4cm*4cm of 2Oz copper would be right.

Comment: I prefer to keep this as simple as possible. A voltage regulator adds to cost and complexity

Comment: Ok, good luck with your design Joseph!